# How to use HAML inside a .vue file in vue 3-rc.3

Tags: vue.js, haml

I am trying to use HAML inside the `.vue`file in the vue version 3 but it is not working.

What I did.

- Intall vue cli version 3.0.0-rc.3
- Created a new project with:

My package is:

```
{
  "name": "project 3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "haml": "^0.4.3",
    "haml-haml-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "hamljs": "^0.6.2",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

In the old `vue cli` version 2 with pwa template it worked fine, my package.json for the one that works:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "Ruan Carlos <ruanltbg@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "haml": "^0.4.3",
    "haml-haml-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "hamljs": "^0.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chalk": "^2.1.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.4.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.1.3",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.8.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.5",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "sinon": "^4.0.1",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.14.0",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.5",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.15",
    "chromedriver": "^2.33.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.1.0",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.16",
    "selenium-server": "^3.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.4.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.8",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.7.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.19.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "uglify-es": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Does anybody has any clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS with HAML/Jade/Pug-like templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217279/vuejs-with-haml-jade-pug-like-templating)

Comment: HI @EmileBergeron, it is not duplicated with that question. His cli version is supposed to be two as the version 3 is only 3 days old.

Comment: Vue CLI is just a tool to get started, it doesn't matter once the project is created.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I understand that but yet if you create a project using `vue cli v2.9.3` and one using `vue cli 3.0.0-rc3` the project is entirely different as the version two uses a template and the version 3 uses plugins. And my question is exactly there, if I create a project using the version 2 it works, but if I create it in the version 3 it just do not work. I need to find the difference between these two.